# How to align the icon of a marker in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In google map usually the center bottom of the image of the marker is the lat lng of a point that it has to mark.

Imagine my marker icon is a circle, I would like the center of it to be at the lat-lng of the given point...

**Code:**

```
var image_hotspot = 'img/icons/bank_euro.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: placeLoc,
      icon: image_hotspot
    });
```

Answer (score 38):

What You need is to create a `MarkerImage` object, for example:

```
var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/icons/bank_euro.png',
                new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(15, 15));
```

Where first parameter is an image url, second is image size, third is origin point of image, and fourth is position on the image where marker should point.
If your marker is a circle then set fourth parameter to center of the image.
And create your marker passing `markerImage` to icon property:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: placeLoc,
  icon: markerImage
});
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/D-7uLsch28c Says that the MarkerImage object is deprecated in favor of the google.maps.Icon object

Answer (score 13):

From the docs:

**Converting MarkerImage objects to type Icon**

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    place.icon,
    new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    new google.maps.Size(25, 25));
```

becomes

```
var image = {
  url: place.icon,
  size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
};
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Answer (score 11):

With v3 of google Maps you could / should use:

```
new maps.Marker({
            ...
            icon: {
                url: '.../myimage.png',
                scaledSize: new maps.Size(60, 30),
                anchor: new maps.Point(30, 30),
            },
        });
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon

Comment: is it not possible to exchange the `.png` with `.svg`? Otherwise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs might be a solution if the browser in question supports svg of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using addMarker and need set the x,y coordinates using Point(x, y)

```
let markerInstance = mapInstance.addMarker({
            lat : _lat,
            lng : _lng,
            label: '8',
            icon : {
              url :  'url_image.png',
              origin:  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            }
        });
```